# Detailed form plugin, with ability to export to excel etc. OR edit PDF live?

Tags: plugins, forms

I have a client who wants to have online application forms for their non profit service.

I have used Contact Form 7 in the past, since its pretty flexible and you can have lots of fields, radio buttons etc which I LOVE.

The only concern is that just sends a plain text email, they want a way that they can save the data into a spreadsheet or database of some sort. Weither it attaches a xml to an email when the form is filled, or it saves it in the admin where you can then export it.

Is there anything out there like this?

OR is there even a way to have a PDF online where people can type in it, fill it in then email it off? Since all the documents are in PDF form already this would be even easier.

Comment: Sincere advice - convince your client that CSV is good enough for Excel-like export. Otherwise you are in for world of pain with these requirements. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Contact Form 7 to Database Extension](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/) plugin will save the form data to the database. I haven't used it myself, so don't know whether it offers easy ways of then extracting it, or if you have to deal with extracting it yourself.

Comment: good to know as I like Contact form 7. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Both Formidable Pro and Gravity Forms allow you to have each be emailed at the time of submission *and* export all entries later as CSV / Excel. Best of luck!